# How to find old CSS value before it was changed by javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently changing the system provided CSS variables using javascript using the code

```
document.body.style.setProperty("--rh__primary-base", "rgba(254,80,0)");
```

When I inspect element however, I see that the old value of `--rh__primary-base` still exists in the code just crossed out. Is there any way to get the old value of `--rh__primary-base` without removing the current value of what I changed?

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything ? revert, initial, .. ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, how would one use those to get a style with JavaScript? My only thought would be to store and remove the inline styles, read the value, and restore the inline styles.

Comment: If you absolutely know that the variable is only set on say body (as in your example) unless you change it for a specific element, you could try document.body.getPropertyValue('--variablename') but you've got to be pretty sure of who is setting it when so I'd save it first before updating it to be safe.

Comment: @isherwood , the idea was to find out if he had tried anything prior asking,. revert,or initial are CSS values, nothing more. To store the exact value is different indeed. js is required: eexample ;) https://jsfiddle.net/xd6z39hy/

Answer (score 0):

Save this value to variable before changing, there is no other way to get old value.